# Homestead: How to upgrade PHP version

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I installed a year ago Homestead with Laravel 5.5.

Now I want to upgrade to Laravel 5.6.

I upgraded Homestead as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#updating-homestead) with

```
vagrant box update
git pull origin master
```

This forced me also to upgrade my `vagrant` to `2.1.2`.

Now when I log in with

`vagrant ssh`

I cannot upgrade to Laravel 5.6, because when I run `composer update` I get this warning:

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
>   resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - This package requires php >=7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.27; Package overridden via config.platform (actual: 7.1.7)) does not
>   satisfy that requirement.   Problem 2
>       - laravel/framework v5.6.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.1.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) overridden by
>   "config.platform.php" version (7.0.27) does not satisfy that
>   requirement.

If I call `php -v` in the vagrant machine I get

> PHP 7.1.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2017 09:41:45) ( NTS )

Which would be okay because Laravel only requires `PHP 7.1.3`, but the upgrade gets stucks because composer claims I am using `PHP 7.0.27`.

WHy is that and how can I fix it?

I even tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

as suggested [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-upgrade-php-mysql-in-homestead) but it still does not work. Some packages have been kept back on the upgrade:

> The following packages have been kept back:   libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm2
>   libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libgd3 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
>   libglapi-mesa   libwayland-egl1-mesa mssql-tools open-vm-tools
>   php7.1-bcmath php7.1-cli php7.1-common php7.1-curl   php7.1-dev
>   php7.1-fpm php7.1-gd php7.1-imap php7.1-intl php7.1-json
>   php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mysql   php7.1-opcache php7.1-pgsql
>   php7.1-readline php7.1-soap php7.1-sqlite3 php7.1-xml php7.1-zip 0
>   upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is actually part of your question. If we have a second look at the composer error:

> Problem 1 - This package requires php >=7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.0.27; Package overridden via **config.platform** [...]

This means you do have something like the following in your `composer.json`, which you need to change or remove prior to the update:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.0.7"
    },
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
```

You can change it to the actual platform version or remove it at all. It is used to emulate an environment, which can be handy if you want to check if you could for example run `composer install` on your server when it has another PHP version than your development machine.

Comment: Just remove `"platform": {
        "php": "7.0.7"
    },`  ?

Comment: I added an explanation in my answer, which might give you an idea what it does. So yes, go ahead and remove it or set it to your new PHP version.

Comment: This is the answer to the question but please note that that platform variable might have been intentional. Maybe your deployment server only has php 7.0.7, so you upgrading your local php version is bound to create the exact same errors later on when you deploy again.

Comment: @Loek Well, then they shouldn't update to Laravel 5.6. :)

Comment: Haha yep, but I've seen so many people make "mistakes" like this, I just thought to point it out.