# Laravel 5.3 Interface Throwable not found at DriverException.php line 33

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, shared-hosting

Last day I uploaded my Laravel project to the server. Everything was working fine like on the local system. Since today morning, When the user submits one of the POST requests, it throws the above error and rests all requests are working fine.

I tried with

`composer dump-autoload
cleared route and cache`

Here is the DriverException.php

```
    <?php
/*
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many individuals
 * and is licensed under the MIT license. For more information, see
 * <http://www.doctrine-project.org>.
 */

namespace Doctrine\DBAL\Driver;

/**
 * Contract for a driver exception.
 *
 * Driver exceptions provide the SQLSTATE of the driver
 * and the driver specific error code at the time the error occurred.
 *
 * @author Steve M端ller <st.mueller@dzh-online.de>
 * @link   www.doctrine-project.org
 * @since  2.5
 */
interface DriverException extends \Throwable
{
    /**
     * Returns the driver specific error code if available.
     *
     * Returns null if no driver specific error code is available
     * for the error raised by the driver.
     *
     * @return integer|string|null
     */
    public function getErrorCode();

    /**
     * Returns the driver error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMessage();

    /**
     * Returns the SQLSTATE the driver was in at the time the error occurred.
     *
     * Returns null if the driver does not provide a SQLSTATE for the error occurred.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getSQLState();
}
```

But none helped me.

Comment: Can you show us the full code of your `DriverException` class?

Comment: Yeah, I have added `DriverException `.please have a look

Comment: Is your server running a PHP version >= 7.0.0?

Comment: no,php version is 5.6

Comment: Have you updated dependencies recently? If not try deleting vendor and running `composer install` again

Comment: Oh Yes,`zip` was not included on my server. So, I have added it. In order to make chumper zipper work on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is not the answer you were hoping for, but the problem is that you are using code that is written for PHP 7. The [`Throwable`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.throwable.php) interface was first introduced in PHP 7 and code using it will therefore not work on an older PHP version.

My best guess is that, especially because the exception you showed is from a vendor package, that your own code base is fine and only a dependency is causing a problem (because you recently updated your dependencies). To solve this issue, what you can do is emulate a lower PHP version for your project within the `composer.json` than what your development machine is running (you seem to run PHP 7 there). composer itself will, without such a setting, always attempt to update to the latest packages compatible with the machine being run on (and of course with regards to the versions defined in the `composer.json`).

Incidentally, just yesterday I answered a question where the exact feature I'm going to suggest now caused troubles ([Homestead: How to upgrade PHP version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100502/homestead-how-to-upgrade-php-version/51100657#51100657)), but in your case it will help. So please go ahead and add the following configuration part to your `composer.json` (best with the exact PHP version your server is running):

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.6.0"
    }
}
```

If there is already a `config` block in the `composer.json`, simply add the `platform.php` parameter to it. After that, run `composer update` to (most likely) downgrade the problematic packages.

In case this doesn't solve the issue, you might need to manually find the problematic packages and lower the versions of them so that they work with your production PHP version.

Comment: Thanks, @Namoshek for your time. your answer helped me indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Throwable is a PHP 7.0+ concept. 
Are you sure you're not using DBAL version incompatible with your PHP? DriverException extends Throwable only in 2.6 which requires PHP 7.1.
So what you need to do is to check your server configuration if it complies ie runs php>7.1 and has the DBAL extension installed.